# R: Vectorizing a condition

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

I have a dataset with over a million rows and 67 columns. I create a new column that records scores according to my code below.

I am stuck at a condition I need to take care of in:

```
DF$change[DF[,63] == "M"] <- DF$change[DF[,63] == "M"] - pos2
```

When `DF$change[DF[,63] == "M"] - pos2 = 0` I need to see if this happend on the bidside or the askside. The way I can determine that is by seeing if the position of DF[,64] is even(askside) or odd(bidside). There's a caveat, I can't use the value from  `pos2` , that I have already calculated, to do this because of my function called `mywhich`(I can provide code if needed) used in the code.
So to determine even/odd I have to recalculate the position of DF[,64]. Once I know even or odd, DF$change should be either -1 or 1 depending on whether DF[,66] > DF[,64] or <.

Now, I've tried subsetting but I don't see how that can work because I have recalculate the positions. I tried not using `mywhich` for this part but I cant seem to get my head around it to make it work.

Any pointers/suggestions? What else I should I try? Should I write a separate function that handles this? Write another version of a which function? I am a little lost

This is what I have so far:

```
 > DF$change <- apply(DF[, 1:62] == DF[,64], 1, mywhich)
    > DF$change[DF[,63] == "C"] <- apply(DF[which(DF[,63] == "C") - 1, 1:62] == DF[DF[,63] == "C",64], 1, mywhich)*(-1) 
    > pos2 <- apply(DF[which(DF[,63] == "M") - 1, 1:62] == DF[DF[,63] == "M",66], 1, mywhich) 
    > DF$change[DF[,63] == "M"] <- DF$change[DF[,63] == "M"] - pos2
```

This is the output:

```
> head(DF, 20)
                  DateTime  Seq   BP1 BQ1 BO1   AP1 AQ1 AO1   BP2 BQ2 BO2   AP2 AQ2 AO2   BP3 BQ3 BO3   AP3 AQ3 AO3   BP4 BQ4 BO4   AP4 AQ4 AO4   BP5 BQ5 BO5   AP5 AQ5 AO5 BP6 BQ6 BO6   AP6 AQ6 AO6 BP7 BQ7 BO7   AP7 AQ7 AO7 BP8 BQ8 BO8 AP8 AQ8 AO8 BP9 BQ9 BO9 AP9
1  2015-11-30 09:15:00.368   92 80830   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0   0   0   0     0   0   0   0   0   0     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2  2015-11-30 09:15:00.368  108 80830   1   1 83435   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0   0   0   0     0   0   0   0   0   0     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3  2015-11-30 09:15:00.375  406 81100   1   1 83435   1   1 80830   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0   0   0   0     0   0   0   0   0   0     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4  2015-11-30 09:15:00.375  479 81100   1   1 82165   1   1 80830   1   1 83435   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0   0   0   0     0   0   0   0   0   0     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5  2015-11-30 09:15:00.377  643 81100   1   1 82165   1   1 80830   1   1 83200   1   1     0   0   0 83435   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0     0   0   0   0   0   0     0   0   0   0   0   0     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
6  2015-11-30 09:15:00.378  722 81100   1   1 82165   1   1 80830   1   1 82650   1   1     0   0   0 83200   1   1     0   0   0 83435   1   1     0   0   0     0   0   0   0   0   0     0   0   0   0   0   0     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
7  2015-11-30 09:15:00.380  811 81100   1   1 82165   1   1 80830   1   1 82650   1   1     0   0   0 83200   1   1     0   0   0 83430   1   1     0   0   0 83435   1   1   0   0   0     0   0   0   0   0   0     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
8  2015-11-30 09:15:00.380  822 81100   1   1 82165   1   1 80835   1   1 82650   1   1 80830   1   1 83200   1   1     0   0   0 83430   1   1     0   0   0 83435   1   1   0   0   0     0   0   0   0   0   0     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
9  2015-11-30 09:15:00.380  828 81100   1   1 82345   1   1 80835   1   1 82650   1   1 80830   1   1 83200   1   1     0   0   0 83430   1   1     0   0   0 83435   1   1   0   0   0     0   0   0   0   0   0     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
10 2015-11-30 09:15:00.383 1046 81100   1   1 82345   1   1 80835   1   1 82650   1   1 80830   1   1 83200   1   1     0   0   0 83430   1   1     0   0   0 83435   1   1   0   0   0 83500   1   1   0   0   0     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
11 2015-11-30 09:15:00.384 1103 81100   1   1 82165   1   1 80835   1   1 82650   1   1 80830   1   1 83200   1   1     0   0   0 83430   1   1     0   0   0 83435   1   1   0   0   0 83500   1   1   0   0   0     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
12 2015-11-30 09:15:00.384 1171 81100   1   1 82345   1   1 80835   1   1 82650   1   1 80830   1   1 83200   1   1     0   0   0 83430   1   1     0   0   0 83435   1   1   0   0   0 83500   1   1   0   0   0     0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
13 2015-11-30 09:15:00.384 1186 81100   1   1 82345   1   1 80835   1   1 82650   1   1 80830   1   1 82900   1   1     0   0   0 83200   1   1     0   0   0 83430   1   1   0   0   0 83435   1   1   0   0   0 83500   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
14 2015-11-30 09:15:00.384 1196 81100   1   1 82165   1   1 80835   1   1 82650   1   1 80830   1   1 82900   1   1     0   0   0 83200   1   1     0   0   0 83430   1   1   0   0   0 83435   1   1   0   0   0 83500   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
15 2015-11-30 09:15:00.385 1238 81100   1   1 82340   1   1 80835   1   1 82650   1   1 80830   1   1 82900   1   1     0   0   0 83200   1   1     0   0   0 83430   1   1   0   0   0 83435   1   1   0   0   0 83500   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
16 2015-11-30 09:15:00.385 1249 81100   1   1 82340   1   1 80835   1   1 82650   1   1 80830   1   1 82900   1   1     0   0   0 83200   2   1     0   0   0 83430   1   1   0   0   0 83435   1   1   0   0   0 83500   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
17 2015-11-30 09:15:00.385 1254 81200   1   1 82340   1   1 81100   1   1 82650   1   1 80835   1   1 82900   1   1 80830   1   1 83200   2   1     0   0   0 83430   1   1   0   0   0 83435   1   1   0   0   0 83500   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
18 2015-11-30 09:15:00.387 1273 81200   1   1 82340   1   1 81100   1   1 82650   1   1 80835   1   1 82900   1   1 80830   1   1 83200   2   1 80035   1   1 83430   1   1   0   0   0 83435   1   1   0   0   0 83500   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
19 2015-11-30 09:15:00.388 1333 81200   1   1 82165   1   1 81100   1   1 82650   1   1 80835   1   1 82900   1   1 80830   1   1 83200   2   1 80035   1   1 83430   1   1   0   0   0 83435   1   1   0   0   0 83500   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
20 2015-11-30 09:15:00.388 1343 81200   1   1 82340   1   1 81100   1   1 82650   1   1 80835   1   1 82900   1   1 80830   1   1 83200   2   1 80035   1   1 83430   1   1   0   0   0 83435   1   1   0   0   0 83500   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   AQ9 AO9 BP10 BQ10 BO10 AP10 AQ10 AO10 C Price Qty OldPrice OldQty change
1    0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0 N 80830   1       NA     NA      5
2    0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0 N 83435   1       NA     NA      5
3    0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0 N 81100   1       NA     NA      5
4    0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0 N 82165   1       NA     NA      5
5    0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0 N 83200   1       NA     NA      4
6    0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0 N 82650   1       NA     NA      4
7    0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0 N 83430   1       NA     NA      2
8    0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0 N 80835   1       NA     NA      4
9    0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0 M 82345   1    82165      1      0
10   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0 N 83500   1       NA     NA      0
11   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0 M 82165   1    82345      1      0
12   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0 M 82345   1    82165      1      0
13   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0 N 82900   1       NA     NA      3
14   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0 M 82165   1    82345      1      0
15   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0 M 82340   1    82165      1      0
16   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0 N 83200   1       NA     NA      2
17   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0 N 81200   1       NA     NA      5
18   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0 N 80035   1       NA     NA      1
19   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0 M 82165   1    82340      1      0
20   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0 M 82340   1    82165      1      0

> dput(DF[1:20,])
structure(list(DateTime = structure(c(1448855100.369, 1448855100.369, 
1448855100.375, 1448855100.376, 1448855100.378, 1448855100.379, 
1448855100.38, 1448855100.38, 1448855100.38, 1448855100.383, 
1448855100.384, 1448855100.385, 1448855100.385, 1448855100.385, 
1448855100.386, 1448855100.386, 1448855100.386, 1448855100.387, 
1448855100.389, 1448855100.389), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), Seq = c(92L, 108L, 406L, 479L, 643L, 722L, 811L, 
822L, 828L, 1046L, 1103L, 1171L, 1186L, 1196L, 1238L, 1249L, 
1254L, 1273L, 1333L, 1343L), BP1 = c(80830L, 80830L, 81100L, 
81100L, 81100L, 81100L, 81100L, 81100L, 81100L, 81100L, 81100L, 
81100L, 81100L, 81100L, 81100L, 81100L, 81200L, 81200L, 81200L, 
81200L), BQ1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), BO1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), AP1 = c(0L, 83435L, 83435L, 82165L, 82165L, 82165L, 82165L, 
82165L, 82345L, 82345L, 82165L, 82345L, 82345L, 82165L, 82340L, 
82340L, 82340L, 82340L, 82165L, 82340L), AQ1 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), AO1 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), BP2 = c(0L, 0L, 80830L, 80830L, 
80830L, 80830L, 80830L, 80835L, 80835L, 80835L, 80835L, 80835L, 
80835L, 80835L, 80835L, 80835L, 81100L, 81100L, 81100L, 81100L
), BQ2 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), BO2 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), AP2 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 83435L, 83200L, 82650L, 82650L, 82650L, 82650L, 82650L, 
82650L, 82650L, 82650L, 82650L, 82650L, 82650L, 82650L, 82650L, 
82650L, 82650L), AQ2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), AO2 = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), BP3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 80830L, 80830L, 
80830L, 80830L, 80830L, 80830L, 80830L, 80830L, 80830L, 80835L, 
80835L, 80835L, 80835L), BQ3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), BO3 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), AP3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 83435L, 83200L, 83200L, 
83200L, 83200L, 83200L, 83200L, 83200L, 82900L, 82900L, 82900L, 
82900L, 82900L, 82900L, 82900L, 82900L), AQ3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), AO3 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), BP4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 80830L, 80830L, 80830L, 
80830L), BQ4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), BO4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), AP4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 83435L, 83430L, 83430L, 83430L, 
83430L, 83430L, 83430L, 83200L, 83200L, 83200L, 83200L, 83200L, 
83200L, 83200L, 83200L), AQ4 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), AO4 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), BP5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 80035L, 80035L, 80035L), BQ5 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), BO5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), AP5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 83435L, 83435L, 83435L, 83435L, 83435L, 83435L, 83430L, 
83430L, 83430L, 83430L, 83430L, 83430L, 83430L, 83430L), AQ5 = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), AO5 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), BP6 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), BQ6 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), BO6 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
    AP6 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 83500L, 83500L, 
    83500L, 83435L, 83435L, 83435L, 83435L, 83435L, 83435L, 83435L, 
    83435L), AQ6 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), AO6 = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), BP7 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), BQ7 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), BO7 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AP7 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 83500L, 83500L, 
    83500L, 83500L, 83500L, 83500L, 83500L, 83500L), AQ7 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), AO7 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), BP8 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), BQ8 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), BO8 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AP8 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AQ8 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AO8 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), BP9 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), BQ9 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), BO9 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AP9 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AQ9 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AO9 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), BP10 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), BQ10 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), BO10 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AP10 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AQ10 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), AO10 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), C = structure(c(4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("", "C", "M", "N"), class = "factor"), 
    Price = c(80830L, 83435L, 81100L, 82165L, 83200L, 82650L, 
    83430L, 80835L, 82345L, 83500L, 82165L, 82345L, 82900L, 82165L, 
    82340L, 83200L, 81200L, 80035L, 82165L, 82340L), Qty = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), OldPrice = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 82165L, NA, 82345L, 82165L, NA, 82345L, 82165L, NA, NA, 
    NA, 82340L, 82165L), OldQty = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L), change = c(5, 
    5, 5, 5, 4, 4, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 2, 5, 1, 0, 0)), .Names = c("DateTime", 
"Seq", "BP1", "BQ1", "BO1", "AP1", "AQ1", "AO1", "BP2", "BQ2", 
"BO2", "AP2", "AQ2", "AO2", "BP3", "BQ3", "BO3", "AP3", "AQ3", 
"AO3", "BP4", "BQ4", "BO4", "AP4", "AQ4", "AO4", "BP5", "BQ5", 
"BO5", "AP5", "AQ5", "AO5", "BP6", "BQ6", "BO6", "AP6", "AQ6", 
"AO6", "BP7", "BQ7", "BO7", "AP7", "AQ7", "AO7", "BP8", "BQ8", 
"BO8", "AP8", "AQ8", "AO8", "BP9", "BQ9", "BO9", "AP9", "AQ9", 
"AO9", "BP10", "BQ10", "BO10", "AP10", "AQ10", "AO10", "C", "Price", 
"Qty", "OldPrice", "OldQty", "change"), row.names = c(NA, 20L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Scroll down to find dput(DF)

Comment: Can you provide some data that would work for this `if` statement and the result it's suppose to produce?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I have posted what you asked for.

Comment: @JeremyS. You don't have to help me if you don't want to, its not an obligation. Besides, what you just asked me not to do is exactly what this website is meant for and what I was suggested to do by you and couple other people on the question I posted yesterday. I am obviously asking this question because its not "easy" for me. If the problem is how I framed the question, I can add more info as required. Thank you for your concern though!

Comment: This is almost the same, but now you want to evaluate variations of `DF$change[DF$change%%2 == 0 & df[,66] > df[,64], ]` and replace. The website it meant to help when you get stuck, not just do it for you.

Comment: Firstly, I didn't realise you can use the & operator here like that, thank you. But thats not exactly what Im looking for. `DF$change[DF[,63] == "M"  & df$change == 0 & #if position is even & df[,66] > df[,64]] <- ......`
And yes I got stuck, I tried a few variations, hence I asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came to the bottom of this, I figured I could create as many new column I wanted in order to calculate what I had to so that's what I did. I think this is the best way to do it but am open to suggestions if there are other ways or even faster.

Here is my code:

```
DF<- read.csv(file = file,header = FALSE,sep = "", col.names = c("DateTime","Seq","BP1","BQ1","BO1","AP1","AQ1","AO1","BP2","BQ2","BO2","AP2","AQ2","AO2","BP3","BQ3","BO3","AP3","AQ3","AO3","BP4","BQ4","BO4","AP4","AQ4","AO4","BP5","BQ5","BO5","AP5","AQ5","AO5","BP6","BQ6","BO6","AP6","AQ6","AO6","BP7","BQ7","BO7","AP7","AQ7","AO7","BP8","BQ8","BO8","AP8","AQ8","AO8","BP9","BQ9","BO9","AP9","AQ9","AO9","BP10","BQ10","BO10","AP10","AQ10","AO10","C","Price","Qty","OldPrice","OldQty"))
DF<- DF[which(DF$DateTime != 0),]
options(digits.secs = 3)
DF$DateTime= as.POSIXct(DF$DateTime/(10^9), origin="1970-01-01", tz = "GMT")    #timestamp conversion

source('~/R/mywhich.R')
source('~/nwhich.R')

#matching with same line for all 
DF$change <- apply(DF[, 1:62] == DF[,64], 1, mywhich)

#matching "C" with previous line 
DF$change[DF[,63] == "C"] <- apply(DF[which(DF[,63] == "C") - 1, 1:62] == DF[DF[,63] == "C",64], 1, mywhich)*(-1)                                                   

#matching old price with previous line in "M"                                                
pos2 <- apply(DF[which(DF[,63] == "M") - 1, 1:62] == DF[DF[,63] == "M",66], 1, mywhich)                                                 

#subracting the two position in "M"
DF$change[DF[,63] == "M"] <- DF$change[DF[,63] == "M"] - pos2

# arbitrary number to create side
DF$side <- 1000

DF$side[DF[,63] == "M" & DF[,68] == 0] <- apply(DF[which(DF[,63] == "M"), 1:62] == DF[DF[,63] == "M",64], 1, nwhich)%%2    #check this -- erroneous for modifications that have happend outside level 5 -- might have to add another column for this
#DF$side[DF[,63] == "M" & DF[,68] != 0] <- DF$change[DF[,63] == "M" & DF[,68] != 0]  
#DF$side[DF[,63] == "N"] <- DF$change[DF[,63] == "N"]
#DF$side[DF[,63] == "C"] <- DF$change[DF[,63] == "C"]
DF$diff <- 0
#price difference
DF$diff[DF[,63] == "M" & DF[,68] == 0] <-  DF$OldPrice[DF[,63] == "M" & DF[,68] == 0] - DF$Price[DF[,63] == "M" & DF[,68] == 0]     
#askside -- price increase
DF$modify[DF[,69] == 0 & DF[,70] > 0] <- -1
#askside -- price decrease
DF$modify[DF[,69] == 0 & DF[,70] < 0] <- 1
#bidside -- price decrease
DF$modify[DF[,69] == 1 & DF[,70] < 0] <- -1
#bidside -- price increase
DF$modify[DF[,69] == 1 & DF[,70] > 0] <- 1
#copying change to modify
DF$modify[DF[,63] == "N"] <- DF$change[DF[,63] == "N"]
DF$modify[DF[,63] == "C"] <- DF$change[DF[,63] == "C"]
DF$modify[DF[,63] == "M" & DF[,68] != 0] <- DF$change[DF[,63] == "M" & DF[,68] != 0]

df = data.frame(Time=DF$DateTime, Modify = DF$modify)
finalxts <- as.xts(x = df$Modify, order.by = df$Time)
#finalxts <- aggregatets(finalxts, FUN = "sum", on = "minutes", k = 1, dropna = TRUE)
finalxts
```

Thank you for the help everyone.